# How can I create a custom date in "snippets" in the Geany text editor?

Tags: date, code-snippets, geany

I often use the Geany text editor to write programming code. I recently knew that we can insert a code snippet in Geany automatically using some keybindings and I liked the idea of that.

So, I went through some of the basics of the snippets in the Geany manual.

And I tried to do this: A required snippet for an [Octave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave) script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/octave -qf
% Author   : Bhishan Poudel
% Date     :
```

I_like_this_to_be_inserted_automatically

My attempt so far:

We have to edit the configuration file called "snippets.conf" which can be accessed like this:

Menu *Tools* → *Configuration Files* → *snippets.conf*

Or `~/.config/geany/snippets.conf`.

Then, I first checked the file type for Octave scripts:

```
geany --ft-names
```

I see the filetype is `[Matlab/Octave]`. So, I added the following code there.

```
[Matlab/Octave]
pre=#!/usr/bin/octave -qf \n% Author    : Bhishan Poudel \n% Date      : {date}\n\n
```

Note: to find the shebang path for octave installation directory, type `which octave`

Then to implement the code I created a file called `a.m` and opened it in Geany. Then the command to try this snippet is *pre<kbd>Tab</kbd> (type `pre` followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd>) then the output is:

```
#!/usr/bin/octave -qf
% Author    : Bhishan Poudel
% Date      : 2016-05-23
```

How can we change the date format to *May 23, 2016*?

Some useful links are following:
http://www.geany.org/manual/0.18.1/index.html#user-definable-snippets

Comment: I don't think this is really relevant to Octave nor MATLAB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to use `{command: date}` with date's default command line syntax. So in your case I think it would be

```
{command:date +"%b %d, %Y"}
```

Which results here into:

```
$ LANG=C date +"%b %d, %Y"
May 24, 2016
```

Another more general way would be to set up a template for your Octave scripts. Inside your template you should be able to insert values based on Geany's configuration. Have a look into [the manual](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#template-preferences), but something like this saved as a template could work (untested):

```
#!/usr/bin/octave -qf
% Author    : {developer} <{mail}>
% Date      : {date}
```

But you would need to configure date-format in Geany's preferences — where you can use the options from above.

Comment: What is the line break symbol in geany configuration? To make a template I have make very long line, is there way I can do line break?

Comment: Not sure where you want to add it, but try \n

Comment: Also what is %b symbol, is this same as %m?

Comment: Here, new line is \n. I am talking about line break symbol \ (such as in C or Python), ... (in matlab/octave).

Comment: Inside a template you can use normal line breaks. Snippets doesn't support line breaks.

Comment: Yes, it works. For an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date, `{command:date +"%Y-%m-%d"}` (sample: *2020-05-22*). For an ISO 8601 date and time, `{command:date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%S"}` (sample: *2020-05-22T160911*).